# Fluorescent light fixture malfunction

Tags: fluorescent

A fluorescent light fixture in my house looks like the attached picture when I turn it on. I replaced the light tube, but no success. If I repeatedly turn it off and then on quickly, it eventually lights up properly. Does this mean that I need to replace the starter? If not, what else might be the issue?

[image: What the light does when I turn it on]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the fixture is stuck in start mode.  It's preheating both ends, but it's not striking.

If it has a starter, replace it.  However, if it doesn't, or if the starter doesn't fix it, it's the [ballast](https://www.lrc.rpi.edu/programs/nlpip/lightingAnswers/adaptableBallasts/ballast.asp) (the bulky part which limits the current passing through the fluorescent bulb).

If you're at the point of replacing the ballast, the replacement ballast might be wired differently - keep close eye on the diagram.  Also, the new ballast would almost assuredly not use a starter.

Another option, instead of replacing starter or ballast, is to rewire for a direct-wire LED "tube".  Don't use a plug-and-play LED because that depends on the ballast/starter working, and yours doesn't.

Comment: OP might not know what a ballast is.

Comment: @einpoklum OP might know what Google is.

Comment: Thank you @Harper. I rewired it for a new direct-wire LED tube. A couple of weeks later, I had to do the same thing for my wife's closet.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t seen a starter for a while, I would change over to a led tube, direct wire or hybrid is the best in my opinion. A friend called me for help last month he purchased plug and play lamps (same problem that you have) but the ballast was bad so his new lamps would not work, I took over some direct wire led lamps removed / bypassed the ballast in a couple of minutes and he had light. If the ballast would have been good a plug and play or a hybrid would have worked but with a bad ballast you need a direct wire or hybrid.